# image background is cut

Tags: css

http://dev.freelanceu.net/mjl/miamischool/
that's my webpage that has a problem in the background, I don't even declared it as no-repeat but still the background was cut at the bottom. I'm confused because in the other page, it's not cut, like this one http://dev.freelanceu.net/mjl/miamischool/forms/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your background image repeats all right - but there's a white bar at the bottom of your image... http://dev.freelanceu.net/mjl/miamischool/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/MCCS_bg.jpg

Comment: great, thanks.. I think I have to tell it to our client who provide us that image.. thanks ptriek!